# How to write Spring unit tests for classes annotated with @ConfigurationProperties?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, unit-testing, junit, configurationproperties

I have a class with configuration properties and I would like to write an unit test in Spring (the application is based on Spring Boot), but I don' want to use `@SpringBootTest`, because the whole application context is loaded for too long.

POM dependencies:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.7.9</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>test-property-demo</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>test-property-demo</name>
    <description>test-property-demo</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>19</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-configuration-processor</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

Production code:

```
package com.example.testpropertydemo.demo;

import lombok.Getter;
import lombok.Setter;
import org.springframework.boot.context.properties.ConfigurationProperties;

@Getter
@Setter
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "demo")
class DemoProperties {

    private String message;
}
```

```
package com.example.testpropertydemo.demo;

import lombok.AllArgsConstructor;

@AllArgsConstructor
public class DemoFacade {

    private final DemoProperties demoProperties;

    public String getHello() {
        return demoProperties.getMessage();
    }
}
```

```
package com.example.testpropertydemo.demo;

import org.springframework.boot.context.properties.EnableConfigurationProperties;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;

@Configuration
@EnableConfigurationProperties(DemoProperties.class)
class DemoConfig {

    @Bean
    DemoFacade demoFacade(DemoProperties  demoProperties) {
        return new DemoFacade(demoProperties);
    }
}
```

Test code:

application.yml

```
demo:
  message: bonjour le monde
```

DemoFacadeTest:

```
@ExtendWith(SpringExtension.class)
@ContextConfiguration(classes = {DemoConfig.class})
@TestPropertySource(locations = "classpath:config/application.yml")
class DemoFacadeTest {

    @Autowired
    private DemoFacade demoFacade;

    @Test
    void getHello() {
        assertEquals("bonjour le monde", demoFacade.getHello());
    }
}
```

**The problem is** I can't force the Spring to read the property file and put the properties to the instance of property configuration class in test. Beans are instantiated correctly, but the `demoProperties` bean is not populated with property coming from `application.yml`

I tried @SpringBootTest and it *does work*, but it is not the solution for me. Context configuration for the app is to heavy to load it in the test.

I tried several configurations of Spring annotations, but nothing worked for me.

Comment: Please double check if application.yml is in the subdirectory config and on the classpath for tests.

Comment: @Mar-Z I checked it, file location is correct

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can limit the context of a springboottest by setting classes

```
@SpringBootTest(classes = {DemoConfig.class})
```

I’m not sure why you’re setting a TestPropertiesSource in a config/ path. If you place the application.yml in the resources folder under java and/or test you shouldn’t have to set that explicitly.

Comment: After experimenting with classes property in `@SpringBoot` annotation I came to the setup where my test run almost as fast as regular unit test. Thanks!